# Model object has no attribute save

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

This is the model I've defined:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MSUser)
    upvote_count = models.IntegerField()
    post_status = models.IntegerField(choices = POST_STATUS)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null = True,blank = True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null = False,blank = False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.content

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user.__unicode__()

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super(Post, self).save(**kwargs)
```

Here is the view:

```
class Post (View):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt) # To be removed
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
#         Placeholder for fine grained permission system to prevent unwarranted GET/POST/PUTS
#          Check request.user properties (like group etc) and request.method 
#             return HttpResponseForbidden()
        return super(Post, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(request):
        pass

    def post(self, request):
        responseMessage = {}  
        user = request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            title = request.POST.get('title', None)
            content = request.POST.get('content', None)
            if title is None or content is None:
                responseMessage['status'] = 'failure'
                responseMessage['message'] = 'Mandatory data is missing.'
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(responseMessage))
            else:
                newPost = Post(user = user,
                               title = title,
                               content = content,
                               post_status = PS_CREATED,
                               upvote_count = 0)
                newPost.save()
                responseMessage['status'] = 'success'
                responseMessage['message'] = 'Post created successfully'
                responseMessage['server_id'] = newPost.id
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(responseMessage))
```

When sending a request from `Postman` I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'save'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Really, you should be using a ModelForm. Then you could use a CreateView and get rid of most of the logic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your view class and the model class have the same name i.e. `Post`.**

So, when you do `Post(user=..)` in your view, it tries to create the `Post` view object and then call `.save()` on it whereas it should have created the `Post` model object and saved it.

To solve your problem, you need to change your view class name to something else.

Try changing

```
class Post(View):
```

to something like

```
class PostView(View):
```

Answer (score 2):

You have duplicated objects named `Post` which you got mixed. It looks like you are trying to save the `View` object instead of the `Model` object.